# Replace named object with properties of that object

Tags: javascript, object

I've been tinkering and was looking at for loops etc, then thought there's probably a quicker way to do this. Then I got lost in the lodash docs...

Anyway, I want to run over the following object—

```
{ 
  stuff: { 
    thing1: 'value1',
    thing2: 'value2',
    thing3: 'value3'
  },
  something: 'value4'
}
```

—and return:

```
{
  thing1: 'value1',
  thing2: 'value2',
  thing3: 'value3',
  something: 'value4'
}
```

That is, I want to eliminate the `stuff` level and have everything as siblings. In an easy / terse way, I mean. I tried `_.flatten` and `._flattenDepth` but they only work with arrays (returns an empty array).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best/only bet is a loop.

```
function flattenObject(obj, res) {
  res = res ? res : {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(d) {
        if (typeof obj[d] === 'object') return flattenObject(obj[d], res);
        res[d] = obj[d];
    });

  return res;
}


console.log(flattenObject(a));
```

Comment: res is the resulting object. In the function's first line I'm just checking if res is passed (already an object), and if not, I create a new empty one. @heydon

Comment: Oh, okay. My reading! I missed that res was in the return line.